# Combining descriptions of abbreviations

Tags: lists, sentence-combination

I want to express the following information in one sentence:

> D-S 
>   D-P stand for difference of probability between the best and the second best match.
>   D-R stand for difference of Reverse between the best and the second best match.

I wrote it as "D-S, D-R and D-P stand for difference of similarity, reverse and probability between the best and the second best match, respectively." Is this correct?

Comment: You seem to have left out most of the first sentence, although it's probably possible to reconstruct it. Better to include that the way you wrote it, though.

Comment: The second sentence does not seem to match the first one, and I don't understand the terminology you are using. That said, the way you used "respectively" seems proper.

Answer (score 1):

Commonly you would sort them in alphabetical order, so D-P, D-R, D-S. I would go with:

> D-P, D-R and D-S stand for the (D)ifference of (P)robability,
>   (R)everse and (S)imilarity between the best and the second best
>   match.

This appears to be leaving out some important data as to what/where the Best and Second Best Match is *drawn from*. I assume the reader will know this.